# How to append <li> dynamically in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a html like this

```
<ul class="list">  
    <div ng-repeat="avis in avisData">  
        <li id="li"> 
            <a class="item item-thumbnail-left" href=""><img src=data:image/jpeg;base64,{{avis.imageClient}} style="width: 100px; height: 100px;"><h3>{{avis.avis.idconsommateur.nom}}&nbsp;&nbsp;{{avis.avis.idconsommateur.prenom}}</h3><p>{{avis.avis.commentaire}}</p></a>
        </li>
        <br>
    </div> 
</ul>

<button class="button button-calm " style="float:right;height: 10px;" ng-controller="AvisEventController" ng-click="ecrireAvis()">
    <div style="float: right;width:80%;">Ecrire</div>
    <div style="margin-top:0px;margin-right:10px;float:left;">

        <i class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg" style="padding-right: 10px;margin-top: -28px;"></i>

    </div>
</button>
```

when i click on button('ecrire'), i want to append one li tag into the ul tag

i have directive like this, i have tried this but it is not working it just add a li in ul without content :

```
$scope.ecrireAvis=function(){

    $scope.consommateur=angular.fromJson($localStorage.UserConsConnect);
    $scope.evenement=angular.fromJson($localStorage.event);
    var objAvis =new Object();
    objAvis.commentaire=$scope.commentaire;
    objAvis.idconsommateur= $scope.consommateur;
    objAvis.idevenement=$scope.evenement;
    alert($localStorage.star);
    objAvis.note=$localStorage.star;

    $http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8080/elodieService/avis/',objAvis).success(function(response, status, headers, config){
        alert("SUCCESS ajout dans la table Avis !!");
        $scope.avisData.push({commentaire:objAvis.commentaire});
    }).error(function(err, status, headers, config){
    //process error scenario.
    });
```

my service web:

```
{
avis: {
commentaire: "aaaaaaaa",
date: null,
idAvis: 8,
idconsommateur: {},
idevenement: {},
imageJson: null,
note: 3
},
imageAvis: null,
imageClient: "/9j/2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJCQgKDBQNDAsLDBkSEw8UHRofHh0aHBwgJC4nICIsIxwcKDcpL
},
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: remove the div ng-repeat, set up the ng-repeat in the `<li id="li">` and change `id̀` with class, because there is maximum 1 id #li per page (id = unique, class = several times)

Comment: In addition to above comment, try this in success function $scope.apply(function(){$scope.avisData.push({commentaire:objAvis.commentaire});});

Comment: @VikramKumar: he is already using $http.post, not jquery $.post . the $scope.$apply is already wrapped.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because you are not binding everything which you need in `avisData` like `imageClient`,`idconsommateur` and don't use `avis.avis` use just `avis` and remove the `div` from `ul` as `ul` must contains `li` like

```
<ul class="list">  
    <li ng-repeat="avis in avisData"> 
        <a class="item item-thumbnail-left" href=""><img src=data:image/jpeg;base64,{{avis.imageClient}} style="width: 100px; height: 100px;"><h3>{{avis.idconsommateur.nom}}&nbsp;&nbsp;{{avis.idconsommateur.prenom}}</h3><p>{{avis.commentaire}}</p></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

in Script push the objeck like,

```
$scope.avisData=[]; //define avisData as array
// http request here
$scope.avisData.push({
   // now commentaire,idconsommateur and imageClient can be directly accessible
   commentaire:objAvis.commentaire,
   idconsommateur:objAvis.idconsommateur,
   imageClient:someOtherObject
});
```

Also I have seen you don't have closing of `$scope.ecrireAvis` function so close it properly.

If you are getting array of objects in response then you need to change above code like,

```
for(var i=0,l=response.length;i<l;i++){
    $scope.avisData.push({
       // now commentaire,idconsommateur and imageClient can be directly accessible
       commentaire:response[i].avis.commentaire,
       idconsommateur:response[i].avis.idconsommateur,
       imageClient:response[i].imageClient
    });
}
```

Comment: look my web service to display 'nom' of 'commentaire' i want  use avis.avis.nom

Comment: Are you getting `response` as an `array`? If not, then why you are using `ng-repeat` and if yes then show me your full array object.